# Get the text out of an WebElement found by id update by jquery

Tags: java, jquery, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get some text out of and id so i can use it later in the test. And i can find the element with:

```
WebElement jrnrText = driver.findElement(
             By.id("ctl00_content_createnewschema_modalAlert_alertMessage"))
```

But the problem is that the value will get dynamically added later by jquery, so the id will be present when i get to the page. I then click a button and jquery will update the id.

I know i can use the  jrnrText.getText() but that will not give me anything since the id don't contain anything before i click the button.

This is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_content_createnewschema_btnCreate")).click();

WebElement jrnrText = driver.findElement(
     By.id("ctl00_content_createnewschema_modalAlert_alertMessage"))

if(jrnrText.isDisplayed()){
    wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath('''//td[contains(text(),"part of the text"]''')))
}

println jrnrText.getText()
```

Comment: Nobody? I have looked into it a bit more and thought that maybe you could use Events with selenium. So after i clicked the button get the source of the page.
But i'm unsure of to do this. It looks like i have to added a FireEventWebDriver and implement and EventListiner put it keeps failing.
here are the API docs if anybody knows or can look at how to do this: https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing, but I will try to answer it.  First off, if an element's ID is dynamically changing based on user input then it is completely defeating the purpose of an ID.  This is a bug that should be fixed in the web site.

If for some reason the bug can't be fixed then we would need more details.  Where in the code that you show above does it fail?  When you say "the id don't contain anything before i click the button" do you mean that the element with an id of "ctl00_content_createnewschema_modalAlert_alertMessage" does not exist?  Even though it is occurring after the button click which you stated updates the ID?

Comment: Sorry about the confusing question. It is not the ID that change it's the value. Here is how it goes:
I click on a button that will do a javascript:__doPostBack. This will call some asp.net code that will generate some text.
Now i got a this: 
<span id="ctl00_content_createnewschema_modalAlert_alertMessage"></span>
When i click the button a (I think jquery popup) will be shown with the text. If i select that popup i can get the source and it will show me this: <pre><code><span id="ctl00_content_createnewschema_modalAlert_alertMessage">The text i want</span></pre></code>

Comment: Ok, so what is failing?  It seems simple enough, you find the button element by ID, you click the button, you find the span by ID and call getText().  At what point is it failing, and what is the error message?  Does it not find the span?

Comment: I get the span but the value will get added dynamically, so when I call getText() the string is empty. My guess is that I have to check if the span is empty and if it's then wait to it gets a value.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand the question.  It sounds like you've got the answer for yourself though.  Just wait for the text to not be an empty string.  Also, ensure that the element is displayed, if it is not displayed then getText will always return an empty string, regardless of whether it is truly empty or not.

Comment: Yeah thanks Sam. But the problem is i don't know how to wait for the getText() to not be empty. I don't know how to say wait.unti(get.Text()!=null) or something like that. My guess would be to have a function that returns true when it can find an element with a Xpath expression that contains text. Do you have any ide on how u can do that with xpath? Look for an id that contains text, any text.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not super familiar with Java, most of what I do is in C#, but I would just do a for loop and inside of that call getText().  If it is an empty string, wait for a couple seconds and try again.  You could try 3 times or so and then fail if it still is an empty string.

Comment: Okay i got it working now, but it's _VERY_ ugly. There are something i need to figure out. Like why it can't find my webelement later down in the code. But for now I just sleep the thread(gah!) and then create a new webelement and get the text. I will have to get a ajaxwait method going asap, and when i do i will post it here. Thanks for all the help Sam! You helped a lot!